# Google preventing login from XAMPP server

Tags: php, xampp, sendmail, sendmail.exe

I am trying to add a confirm email address feature to my web app.
I configured the XAMPP server and changed all the required lines in **php.ini** and **sendmail.ini**
But when I tried to send a mail, I got the following message from Google.

[image: Screenshot of the mail]

Can this be fixed?

I used the following link to configure

[How to configure XAMPP to send mail from localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965376/how-to-configure-xampp-to-send-mail-from-localhost)

The following is the code to send mail.

```
<?php
$to      = 'nikamanish007@gmail.com';
$subject = 'php mail';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'from manish';

if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
{
    echo 'mail sent';
}
else
{
    echo 'mail not sent';
}
?>
```

Comment: Please provide more detail when you configured it, to make it more clear. Do you use OAuth or whatever it's.

Comment: I'm sure this is a Google thing, your solution is to understand their security requirements and use them accordingly.  For example, you may not be using SSL/TLS which could be a requirement.

The error message is right there "Someone just tried to login via an insecure app" However you can disable that somewhere in your config. [See this support FAQ](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to enable **Allow less secure apps: ON** in your gmail account.

1. Go to [Gmail account security](https://myaccount.google.com/security)
2. Click on **Sign-in & Security**
3. Scroll down, there will be an option "Allow less secure apps" which is set to OFF by default, just turn on the setting and check.